# How to get (x, y, z) coordinates of skeletal joints from latest SkeletalViewer? (C++)

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am a student and currently work on a project using multiple kinect cameras. I have to start out my project by acquiring the skeletal joint data from each of the kinect cameras and store them into two text files separately by using SkeletalViewer.

I have made some modifications on SkeletalViewer.h as below:

```
public: 
FILE* filePointer;
char mText[1024];
```

And further modification in NuiImpl.cpp as below:

```
HRESULT CSkeletalViewerApp::Nui_Init() {

    fopen_s(filePointer, "C:/User/Users/Documents/Shasa/Kinect3D.txt", "w+");
    filePointer = NULL;
     .
     .
     .
}

void CSkeletalViewerApp::Nui_DrawSkeleton( const NUI_SKELETON_DATA & skel, int windowWidth, int windowHeight )
{   
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_COUNT; i++)
    {
        m_Points[i] = SkeletonToScreen(skel.SkeletonPositions[i], windowWidth, windowHeight);

        memset(mText, 0, 1024);

        sprintf(mText, "(%0.3f,%0.3f,%0.3f)", skel.SkeletonPositions[i].x, skel.SkeletonPositions[i].y, skel.SkeletonPositions[i].z);

        if (filePointer) {
            fputs((const char*)mText, filePointer);
        }
    }

    if (filePointer) {
        fputs("\n", filePointer);
    }
     .
     .
     .
}
```

The result is the text file is made but the content is blank. I read through some of the solutions online but the previous version of **Nui_DrawSkeleton function** using **NUI_SKELETON_DATA * pSkel** as argument but this new version is different using **NUI_SKELETON_DATA & skel**. Is it correct to use **skel.SkeletonPositions[i].x, skel.SkeletonPositions[i].y, skel.SkeletonPositions[i].z**?

May I seek for anyone's help who can help me to see which cause my error and how to modify it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`skel.SkeletonPositions[i].x` is correct. Using `& skel` instead of `* pskel` will only change `pskel->XXX` to `skel.XXX`.

The problem would be here :

```
fopen_s(filePointer, "C:/User/Users/Documents/Shasa/Kinect3D.txt", "w+");
filePointer = NULL;
```

That should be :

```
fopen_s(&filePointer, "C:/User/Users/Documents/Shasa/Kinect3D.txt", "w+");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the problem to set the filePointer to NULL. I made it as below and it works now!

    if(filePointer) 
 { 
  filePointer = NULL;
 }
    fopen_s(&filePointer, "C:/User/Users/Documents/Shasa/Kinect3D.txt", "w+");

Thank you!

Comment: @EvaChew You can use `fopen_s` alone, because `fopen_s` don't care if `filePointer` is NULL or not. Also, `fopen_s` will return an error code if it fails, or 0 if successful. It can be a good idea to check this value.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help! Could you help me in my other problem like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336226/how-to-initialize-two-kinect-simultaneously-skeletalviewer