# How to initialize two Kinect simultaneously? (SkeletalViewer)

Tags: c++, kinect-sdk

I would like to do skeletal tracking simultaneously from two kinect cameras in SkeletalViewer and obtain the skeleton result. As in my understanding, the Nui_Init() only process the threads for first Kinect (which I suppose index = 0). However could I have the two skeletal tracking run at the same time as I would like to output their result respectively into two text files at the same time.

**(eg. for Kinect 0 output to "cam0.txt" while Kinect 1 output to "cam1.txt")**

Does anyone has experience in such case or able to help?

Regards,

Eva

**PS:** I read this from Kinect SDK documentation state that:

> If you are using multiple Kinect sensors, skeleton tracking works only on the first device that you Initialize.  To switch the device being used to track, uninitialized the old one and initialize the new one.

So is it possible if I want to acquire the coordinates simultaneously? Or even if acquire one by one, how should I call them separately? (as I realize the index of the active Kinect will be 0 which I can't differentiate them).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using MS SkeletalViewer example. The problem with their SkeletalViewer is that they closely tied the display and the skeleton tracking. This make it difficult to change.

Using multiple kinect sensor should be possible, you just need to initialize all the sensors the same way. The best thing to do would be to define a sensor class to wrap kinect sensors. If you don't need the display, you can just write a new program. That's a bit of work but not that much, you can probably get a fully working program for multiple sensors in less than 100 lines. If you need the display, you can rewrite the SkeletalViewer example to use your sensor class but that's more tedious.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to do this by modifying SkeletalViewer and display two color depth data but no skeletal tracking and make two Kinects run simultaneously so that I can get the two sets of data simultaneously?

Comment: @EvaChew Yes, you can draw anything. You just need to initialize and handle the two kinects correctly. Using the SkeletalViewer, you will need to modify everywhere `m_pNuiSensor` is used, and maybe more, because you need  to manage two `INuiSensor*` at the same time. To understand what to modify, you would need to understand how SkeletalViewer works. That's not easy because it only use WinAPI and WinForm, making it harder if you don't know. That's why it might be easier to write your own short sensor class and use a simpler window/graphic library like SDL or Qt.

Comment: Hi I have spent some time to figure out the short sensor class you mean. I think that is a essential for initialize two sensors. But the problem is in the initial SKeletalViewer, there are lots of function which I am not sure if I only took part of them, the code will be able to work well or not? Or do you mind to give an idea about the short sensor class? (to add into the initial project?)

Comment: @EvaChew All you need to initialize a sensor is `NuiCreateSensor` and `NuiInitialize`, plus start functions like `NuiSkeletonTrackingEnable`. It's also probably a good idea to include the `Nui_ProcessThread`, and related members/initializations.

Comment: Thanks I understand what you mean. Recently I am considering to write in WPF app as I need a different UI in my application. I dont think Win32 app is easier for designing GUI on the application. Do you think it is a good way if i make all of this into c# wpf program?

Comment: @EvaChew Using C# and WPF is certainly a good idea, it will much easier than the Win32 WinForm. The Kinect API is a little less flexible in C#, but you should be able to do what you want.